# Postfix alternate transport based on recipient SMTP server

Tags: postfix

Is there a way in Postfix, similar to the transport table, to specify different transports for outbound mail based on a recipient mail server?

In other words, if xyz.com is a large mail hosting provider and it's determined that user@destination.com relays through mx-01.xyz.com, can I configure Postfix to send all *.xyz.com-bound messages through Amazon SES instead without having to enumerate all the possible recipient domains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to be smarter than Postfix? That is how SMTP works. Find the MX for destination.com and send the mails there.

If that is not the final destination, then what do you care? That is the problem of the MX host.

What do you do when the MX of destination.com changes? Do you notice that? Will you make changes in time? Don't change the protocol, just stick to it.